# Can I possibly always display the this TimePicker Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create an app where the user is able to select the time and the date, I want to make it such that the TimePicker is always showing on the screen for the user. I have managed to do this but I am unable to get the Time that is set by the user as there is no `OnChanged` method available.

Furthermore, I cannot change the functionality of the cancel and the Ok button that is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff2E2E42),
      appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: CustomAppBar("Add Alarm")),
      body: Column(

        children: [
          TimePickerDialog(initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(), onEntryModeChanged: (TimePicker){
            print(TimePicker);
            
          },),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 42.0),
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(onPressed: (){pickDate(context);},
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Text(getDate(), style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image: Output]

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to convert `TimePickerDialog` into a non-dialog version, because much of it is hardcoded. This is unlike the date picker counterpart, where we can choose to either use `DatePickerDialog` or standalone `DayPicker`, `MonthPicker`, `YearPicker` widgets.

You basically have 3 choices, none of them is great.

1. Copy the dialog code (`time_picker.dart` file) into your project and modify it to suit your needs.
2. Use `CupertinoTimerPicker` (very different visual style).
3. Create your own, build it however you like.